# HttpWebRequest waiting for timeout period to return 503

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest

I have a very strange issue with C# HttpWebRequest (I cannot post the code because it would be a series of small one-liners from separate files). In WCF as a part of handling one of API requests I send request to other (Java) service to collect some data procces them and return in original WCF query. I use HttpWebRequest to query the external service. The problem occurs when the external service is done. Normally the server returns 503 from Java service to WCF service and WCF should immediately propagate the 503 as the result of initial request, and so happens during debugging. But whenever I quit debugging mode or deploy the service to dev environment it does not propagate the 503 but waits the timeout period (60s) and then returns the 503. This is not the expected behavior. It should always propagate the 503 immedietly. Has anyone ever experienced similar issue. It seems to be unrelated to code itself.

I would be grateful for any help.

Regards

Comment: Can you host this WCF service onto your development machine on IIS or as windows service running under local account and see if it behaves exactly the same as it does on the Dev server?

Comment: I can but this proves nothing. When running it locally I am able to reproduce it but ONLY without the debugger attached. Attaching debugger makes it impossible to reproduce. The code is also located in a place where I cannot do proper logging.

Comment: When you say "locally" do you mean locally hosted or locally on Visual Studio without debugging?

Comment: Hosted locally means hosted on my dev machine's IIS without debugging - with possibility to acces it via localhost from Postman/Webbrowser etc.. I debug it by attaching debugger to IIS service (normal WCF debugging from VS)

Comment: Okay- Are there any certificates used to call that java service? Also may be its wort checking for the security updates on the server. I would even host a mock service on Dev machine with exact same settings that will return a mock response. Im just trying to narrow down the problem area.